# How to Install QueryAnalyzer on Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I don't know if it is just me, but searching on google didn't reveal me answer to my question "How to install QueryAnalyzer for SQL Compact 3.5 DB on Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional emulator device". Does somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the following file on the device:

```
sqlce.dev.ENU.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
```

It can be found on your PC (with SQL CE installed of course) at `%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\armv4i`